# Access subnetwork by networks IP

Tags: router, home-networking, subnet

I have a router in my house which has some IPs assigned.

By default the router creates a sub-network.

Can I access a device in my sub-network (IP example: `192.168.1.3`) from outside that sub-network via the "real IP" that is assigned to my router?

How do I specify the third device from the sub-network IP, example: `16.54.12.32`

Comment: Search for "Port Forwarding" or "Port Triggering".

Comment: Well, you can access SERVICES on the box if you forward them as DavidPostill mentions, but there are limitations. You must target the service on the devices in the other network, not the boxes themselves; they will be inaccessible except through port forwarding rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it by specified ports on router external IP if:
1. Router has REAL Internet external IP
2. Create port forwarding rules. Please refer to http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/default.htm